# Reading adjacent elements in XML

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextreader

I've got a large XML file and so I'm using XMLTextReader. I'm having trouble reading the value becaues the formatting is a bit different from other XML files I've worked with.

```
<class>
   <column>Size</column><int>30</int>
   <column>TeamColor</column><string>red</string>
   ...
</class>
```

How can I read Size and then get the value 30? I've currently got

```
while (reader.Read())
{
     if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)                    
         element = reader.Name;  
     else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
     {
         if (element == "column")
         {
             if(reader.Value == "Size")
             //can get true here, but can't return the int value next to it
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the columns with their name and associated value in the `Hashtable`.

Try using this piece of code snippet:

```
Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();
int intVal;
string prevColumnName = "";

while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        element = reader.Name;
    }
    else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
    {
        switch (element.ToLower())
        {
            case "column":
                prevColumnName = reader.Value;
                hashTable.Add(reader.Value, null);
                break;
            case "int":
                if (int.TryParse(reader.Value, out intVal))
                    hashTable[prevColumnName] = intVal;
                break;
            case "string":
                hashTable[prevColumnName] = reader.Value;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int size = Convert.ToInt32(hashTable["Size"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use xpath, from the `<column>` context node try `(following-sibling::*)[1]`. This will select the elements `*` along following-sibling axis (things that are peers to the context but come after in document order) and then return the first element of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you store the previous value you will need to add a skipping condition allowing you to make an extra read (for the sibling) when it hits the column element and then handle any additional reads properly at the next loop.

```
bool skipRead = false;
while (skipRead || reader.Read())
{
     skipRead = false;
     if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)                    
         element = reader.Name;  
     else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
     {
         if (element == "column")
         {
             if (Reader.Read())
             {
               if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Size")
               {
                   // do whatever you need to here with reader.Value. 
                   // E.g size = (int) reader.Value
                   skipRead = false;
                   continue;
               } // Additional ifs for other elements in column can go here.
               else
               {
                   skipRead = true;
                   continue;
               }
             }
             else
             {
              break;
             }
         }
     }
}
```